# Oracle instant client header files are missed

Tags: c++, oracle, redhat, occi

I'm using RedHat OS to build a C++ program that is using OCCI to connect with an Oracle DB.

I had to reinstall everything and I found that my make file is adding the header files from the following path

> /usr/include/oracle/18.3/client64

Which isn't available anymore

The only installation I remember I need is installing `oracle-instantclient-basic`

I've downloaded the rpm and installed using the command `rpm -i ***.rpm`

But the folder `/usr/include/oracle` isn't there

Note: The path `/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client/lib` is found and all libraries I use for linking are there (only header files are missed).

[This is my installation file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uVyOti5qqHDHnbtDkK-32LA2AtlqkEPK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could investigate and find the solution

The header files are not created by installing `oracle-instantclient-basic` but you should install `oracle-instantclient-devel`

`/usr/include/oracle/18.3/client64` is the path for 64bit version and the path is `/usr/include/oracle/18.3/client` for 32bit versions.

All the tools can be downloaded from [oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxsoft-082809.html)